# What is the best resource for placeholder image files in various formats?

Tags: image, resources, placeholder, image-formats

I'm developing a cross-platform **desktop** application that handles a range of image files: anything from `.jpg`, `.xpm` through to `.tiff`. The application even needs some `.ico` files because it runs in the systray and I want to see that the icons change with changing application states.

As a developer I don't want to spend even ten minutes searching for files.

Is there a definitive one-stop-shop site for placeholder / fake images so that developers can use these just get on with their work, with the intention that they'd be later replaced by a designed image before release?

Comment: fontawesome has lots of icons, so does pictos, and searching for "icon pack"

Comment: So I see... yeah some are potentially useful to me. I'll try to check it out =]

Comment: Hmm. I'm not after web icons. This is for a desktop application!

Comment: that's true, but pictos gives you image files as well, and you can export FA icons using a canvas or [print screen]

Answer (score 3):

if you love kittens here you have resource with cute kittens images:
http://placekitten.com/ ;)

Answer (score 2):

yeah there are some resources out there, which you'll find by using Google.

Here's one: http://placehold.it/

Comment: Yeah, true when I wrote the question originally I used the word 'test image'. Google didn't yield any good results for that!
with Placeholder image... well, everything came up haha.

Comment: glad I could be of service.

Answer (score 1):

You could check out http://lorempixel.com/ - A play on Lorem Ipsum.. only... for pictures instead of typeset.